# Are SMS questions relevant here?

Tags: discussion, scope

**Is it relevant to post a question here about user interface/user experience to a web application via SMS messages?** Would such questions be welcome? And can I add an SMS tag?

We're building a web app that has a bootstrapped responsive design for mobile browsers, and a little SMS capability (account activation via a web link), and are considering adding more functionality for users via SMS (e.g., account activation via SMS, and some simple transactions).

On a whim, we thought we'd ask some teenage friends and relatives to give us ideas about what would make sense to be able to do purely using the text messaging functionality on mobile phones (no web required, no smart phone required). But this would be just a start, a brainstorming exercise.

Googling for case studies and best practices seems to bring up one haystack after another (mostly related to technical implementation).

Related link: [SMS: the ultimate cross-platform mobile app](http://www.triballabs.net/2012/01/sms-the-ultimate-cross-platform-mobile-app/)

I did notice there was [a question on meta that might seem to answer this question already](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/14298). But the absence of such questions makes me wonder if this is the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, UX related questions that happen to involve SMS are on topic and we've got a couple [sms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms) questions already. Go ahead and ask on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Though ux.stackexchange mostly handles questions about visual applications, queries on text interaction, audio UIs and command-line interfaces are all perfectly on-topic.

Comment: As are physical devices, and every aspect of the product that makes the experience